# Are Python prepared statements vulnerable to SQL injection

Tags: python

I'm starting to program a Python application that works with databases. Reading about prepared statements, I found how I'm supposed to write them:

```
...
strSQL = "select * from myTable where aField = $s" % (aValue)
cursor.execute(strSQL)
...
```

My question is: Isn't this vulnerable to SQL injection? If so, how can I prevent it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the [string formatting operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead of [bound SQL parameters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), so your code is indeed at risk of SQL injection (once you fix the `$s`, which I take to be a typo).

The correct form is:

```
strSQL = "select * from myTable where aField = %s"
cursor.execute(strSQL, [aValue])
```

Comment: The OP is not even using string formatting, as the 'template' used is `$s` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I am screwing up by using `$s`. This are my first steps in Python, and I'm trying to correct my mistakes before they become serious.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, absolutely! Here's how you would "help" get around the sql injection

```
strSQL = "select * from myTable where aField = %s"
cursor.execute(strSQL, [aValue])
```

Pass the values as a list/tuple to the second argument on the cursor execute